# How to extract RAR file containing files with Persian or Arabic name

Tags: rar

I have several RAR file which contain several files including few with Persian names. I tried xarchiver software. I can open the archive but if I want to extract the file, it gives error without even extracting files without Persian name.

I tried terminal solution by installing and trying `unrar` and `unrar-free`. I tried to extract using:

```
unrar-free --extract archive.rar
```

and it comes with output like this (I just show small part of the output):

```
Extracting  ST - GOLDM15+++++37M15.png      OK        
Extracting  ST - GOLDM30++++++37M30.png     OK        
Extracting  ST - ������_� 37.docx           Failed    
Extracting  ST - �_��_��� ������_�  �� ������.docx Failed
```

Hopefully it gives me the files with Latin names. But didn't get any success for Persian ones.

How can I solve the problem? I don't want for such thing, go and use Windows!!!
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I was checking for information about different packages related t RAR archives, I Accidentally, noticed this:

```
$ apt show unrar-free
Package: unrar-free
Version: 1:0.0.1+cvs20140707-1
...
...
Description: Unarchiver for .rar files
 Unrar can extract files from .rar archives. Can't handle some archives in
 the RAR 3.0 format natively. Package "unar" can be used to extract those
 archives if installed.
```

So, as suggested in the last sentence, I tried `unar` and it perfectly extracted all the files.

---

It was interesting to not being about to find this valuable piece of information, anywhere else including in manpage of `unrar-free`

---

**update:**

The other way to extract such files is to use `7z`. For this, `p7zip-rar` should be already installed.